# Cordova : Error When adding platform (cannot call method 'replace' of undefined)

Tags: cordova

I am working on cordova for a while and the project was work without any error
yesterday I try to get the latest version from TFS and then I faced this error

`D:\projects\mycordovaProject>cordova platforms add android
Adding android project...
Error: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined`

I try to remove all plugins and platforms but the problem didn't solve
and I try to create new project it's created and working perfectly 
and I try to take a project to run in another laptop, sitll not working with same error.

Comment: remove all platforms before what you have installed and then try again

Comment: I'm having this issue on running iOS version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was in config.xml 
replace

```
<widget android-packageName=""
```

with

```
<widget id=""
```

Comment: This worked for me without replacing just adding 'id'